# Hooking or Monitoring Service Creation

Tags: windows, api, hook

I am at the end of my rope here.  I have been trying for three weeks now to get this information.  Before I continue I want you to know I am not writing malware here.  I am however writing a binary analysis tool that monitors the behavior of malware.

What I am trying to accomplish is either to hook or monitor CreateServiceW and CreateServiceA.  The reason is I want to know what process invoked CreateService and what the binary is that is being registered as a service by the call.

I am tried everything from writing hook ZwRequestWaitReplyPort to intercept the LPC message, to writing a proxy DLL for advapi32.dll, and writing an inline hook for the CreateService function.  None of these approaches have yielded results though.  The proxy DLL was promising in testing, but didn't work when the official DLL in system32 was replaced with the proxy (BSOD).  The inline hook would work if I could gain write access to the mapped area of memory the DLL lies in.  But regardless my time is running out and I am desperately in need of an alternative.

I have looked at SetWindowsHookEx and it seems plausible that it might be able to intercept messages sent from the process to services.exe ...but I am not certain.

Can anyone point me in a good direction...I'm begging you.

Comment: Can't you hook/monitor the registry? Service creation always ends up modifying HKLM\SYSTEM\etc...?

Comment: I already have the registry hooked.  Unfortunately, when a service is registered through CreateService or StartService, it is the SCManager (services.exe) that does the registry modification.  What I want is who called CreateService and what binary was registered =D.

Comment: If my guts feeling is not wrong ZwRequestWaitReplyPort isn't the right way to go (I'm not sure what is). Because ZwRequestWaitReplyPort is an RPC api, meaning it's only delivers a message delivery system. You should try and find the receiving function (because if someone start a service remotely a hook on ZwRequestWaitReplyPort won't catch it).

Answer (score 0):

"The inline hook would work if I could gain write access to the mapped area of memory the DLL lies in."

If it's a system that you fully control, why don't you have write access to the memory?

Use VirtualProtect to change the permissions to RWX and put your hook in. The ADVAPI32 CreateService routines are just stubs forwarded to sechost.dll via api-ms-service-management-l1-1-1.dll (due to MinWin) so there is already easy call instruction to hook.